# Micronaut - Create a bean without creating ApplicationContext

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, micronaut

I have a Micronaut declarative HTTP client written using @client annotation. I want to call this while starting micronaut app before creating the ApplicationContext itslef.

HttpClient : SampleHttpClient.java

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;

@Client("http://127.0.0.1:8200")
@Header(name = "X-Vault-Token", value = "hvs.CEGT7cKyMA8wsDbgKZqxC34q")
public interface SampleHttpClient {
    @Get(value = "/v1/kv/data/KMS", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    HttpResponse<String> getVaultSecret();
}
```

Application.java (Main class)

```
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Following code works perfect. I am creating context here. But I dont want to do this
        SampleHttpClient client = Micronaut.run(Application.class, args).
                getBeansOfType(SampleHttpClient.class).stream().findFirst().get();
        System.out.println("Response Body ="+client.getVaultSecret().body());
   
        // How do we get the instance of SampleHttpClient without using Micronaut's dependency 
injection process???

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call this while starting micronaut app before creating the
> ApplicationContext itslef.

Micronaut doesn't provide a mechanism to support that.  You could write your own thing that instantiates the beans, but that is a large undertaking.  You would be writing your own bean container.

Comment: The issue is that the application context is responsible for creating the bean, so wanting the bean without creating the context is a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had to use Java 11 HTTPClient to do this. It works, but it creates some boiler plate code. This would have been very simple if micronaut supported.

Comment: "This would have been very simple if micronaut supported" - It isn't clear why eliminating the application context is helpful.  Bean management is the primary purpose of the context.  If you have ideas for some other approach please open that up for discussion at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/discussions.  Thank you for your feedback!